# What Event in NextJS Fires Off on only the Initial Load

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, next.js, loading

I have a NextJS app which I want to make have an initial loading screen that only runs on the initial load up. Currently the loading screen runs on the initial load **and** each time a link is clicked which directs the user back to the home screen. I know in React I could just use window.onload(loaded()) but in NextJS how can I achieve the same result without the window object?
**I only want the loaded() function to run one time during the initial app load.**

My code is below, thank you for your help:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import {
  Navbar,
  Hero,
  Showcase,
  Skills,
  Services,
  Footer,
  ProjectCard,
  Loader,
} from '../components';

const Loadera = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-500 h-[100vh] w-[100vw] flex items-center justify-center text-center flex-col">
      <h1 className="text-white mb-4 text-5xl ">Welcome!</h1>
      <h1 className="text-white mb-4 text-2xl ">One Moment Please...</h1>
      <Loader size="lg" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Home() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const loaded = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 1500);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loaded();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Seth&apos;s Place</title>

        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
        ></meta>
      </Head>
      {loading ? (
        <Loadera />
      ) : (
        <div className="min-h-screen">
          <div className="image-bg">
            <Navbar />
            <Hero />
          </div>
          <ProjectCard />
          <Skills />
          <Services />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a flag such that the loading screen only runs when its value is unset/false.
Set its value to true after the initial load. That way, it will only load once.

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import {
  Navbar,
  Hero,
  Showcase,
  Skills,
  Services,
  Footer,
  ProjectCard,
  Loader,
} from '../components';

const Loadera = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-500 h-[100vh] w-[100vw] flex items-center justify-center text-center flex-col">
      <h1 className="text-white mb-4 text-5xl ">Welcome!</h1>
      <h1 className="text-white mb-4 text-2xl ">One Moment Please...</h1>
      <Loader size="lg" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Home() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState({
    load: true,
    loadedOnce: false,
 });

  const loaded = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading({
        load: false,
        loadedOnce: true,
      });
    }, 1500);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loaded();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Seth&apos;s Place</title>

        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
        ></meta>
      </Head>
      {loading.load && !loading.loadedOnce ? (
        <Loadera />
      ) : (
        <div className="min-h-screen">
          <div className="image-bg">
            <Navbar />
            <Hero />
          </div>
          <ProjectCard />
          <Skills />
          <Services />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi friend - that is what I am seeking guidance on. I am asking the name for an event that I can add the flag too. For example, in React apps, where the window object is available, I could add the flag to window.onload() and it would run after first init.
However NextJS does not have the window object so I am wondering what I could use instead to add the flag?

Comment: Just like you used the loading variable to check whether it is loading or not, you can use another variable to check whether it has loaded once or not. I am editing my answer to let you what I would suggest trying. Please mark it as accepted answer if it helps you.